# singularity and github package registry

Tags: docker, singularity-container, github-package-registry

*How to pull a docker image from github registry using singularity?*

Usually with docker you have to generate a token and run sth similar to:
`docker pull docker.pkg.github.com/{etc}/{etc}/{etc} --username {mygithubusername} --password {generatedtoken}`

However,
`singularity pull docker://docker.pkg.github.com/{etc}/{etc}/{etc} --username {mygithubusername} --password {generatedtoken}`

produces: `Error for command "pull": accepts between 1 and 2 arg(s), received 5`

Comment: If you migrate to GHCR you no longer need to authenticate https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/migrating-to-the-container-registry-from-the-docker-registry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For private registries, you can either authenticate interactively:

```sh
singularity pull --docker-login docker://docker.pkg.github.com/{etc}/{etc}/{etc}
Enter Docker Username: mygithubusername
Enter Docker Password:
```

Or via env variables (useful for CI):

```sh
export SINGULARITY_DOCKER_USERNAME=mygithubusername
export SINGULARITY_DOCKER_PASSWORD=generatedtoken
singularity pull docker://docker.pkg.github.com/{etc}/{etc}/{etc}
```

See [the documentation](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.8/user-guide/singularity_and_docker.html#authentication-via-interactive-login) for additional details.